# How to obtain a student visa of another country in the Schengen area?

Tags: visa, students, austria

I have come to Poland from India to study in a university. I have a Type-D National Visa, but, no temporary residence card. I am planning to move to a university of another country in the Schengen area.

First, when I apply for the student visa in the embassy of the new country, will my visa process be any easier for the visa I am already holding?

Secondly, will the embassy want to see my financial proof for the living expense for the whole study period as the embassies located in India generally ask for (For example, now, I have EUR 5500. But, the embassy may want to see the proof of total 24 months' of living expense, that, is EUR 20000) ?

Answer (score 1):

The Schengen agreement/regulations do not cover long-stay visa applications in any way. In very limited cases, some unrelated EU rules could make things slightly easier (e.g. for permanent residents or Blue Card holders) but that's not applicable here. You should be able to lodge an application to the relevant consulate in Poland (as opposed to going back to India) but that's the only difference.

I don't know what they will want to see (it depends on the country) but you will still have to qualify for the relevant visa according to the destination country's own rules, including any financial means requirement, just as you would back in India.